# changing the position of facebook like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, positioning

I just got the code for the new like button (the one that also includes the send button) and I am trying to set it to be in the center of the section it is installed in. However, it always stays on the left side of the section no matter what I do. I tried putting it inside many classes of , align, style or fixed position and none worked.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=202863559776189&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/myid" ref="myPageLocation" send="true" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" font="verdana"></fb:like>
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestion that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably a CSS issue from what I understand.

I have not tested it out, but in concept you could use a  wrapper around your fb:like tag. Setting styles to the fb:like tag most likely won't work out as fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. i tried center wrapper and it changes the position but it is not the correct position. For example, when i use center, it is supposed to be centered but instead it is halfway from the center to the right and when i set right, it jumps to left side of next line.

Comment: I believe it creates an iframe with 450px width by default. You could try setting your wrapper to overflow:hidden, and to a height and width such that only the button is shown. This makes your wrapper in the exact size of the Like button so the whole wrapper can be positioned anywhere you want it to

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did not know about the size of the iframe. I will try this and will post the result.